# how to use binary operator in bash 4.2

Tags: bash

I try to use binary operator to use regexpression power,

```
   [[ wwwebhost@all =~ "^.+@.+$" ]]
```

do not work in bash 4.2 and works in bash 3.2

but this works in bash 4.2(drop the double quote):

```
   [[ wwwebhost@all =~ ^.+@.+$ ]]
```

can anyone explain this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why quote removal isn't performed between \[\[ ... \]\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644663/why-quote-removal-isnt-performed-between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash 4 (actually I thought this was added in 3.2, but maybe not) quotation marks on the right side of a `=~` or `==` operator inside `[[`...`]]` tell `bash` to do simple string comparison rather than regular expression matching.  You might think this would not be the case with the explicit "hey, do a regular expression match!" operator `=~`, but it is.