# why this simple regex does not work in bash 4.1.2?

Tags: regex, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why quote removal isn’t performed between [[ … ]]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644663/why-quote-removal-isnt-performed-between)

```
#!/bin/bash

VER=1.0.3-16

if [[ $VER =~ "1.0.3.*" ]]
then
        echo "Supported"
else
        echo "Not Supported"
fi
```

---

it used to work well in 3.2.25

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? The regex probably should be `"1\.0\.3.*"`, or it would also match `10003`, anyway.

Comment: @kev: Interesting, but shouldn't that change already have been in effect in 3.2.25?

Comment: I think it's not well documented.